# Share build increment across Jenkins multibranch (pipeline) builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was hoping someone could help with ideas in Jenkins for sharing a build increment across multibranch pipelines on multiple build machines.  Looking through similar questions, I didn't see anything better than timestamp instead of build number  but it's not quite what we were looking for.

I am using Jenkinsfiles to define multiple pipelines, then 'multibranch' to instantiate them across all branches.  Currently these just call shared freestyle jobs to implement the stages.  Every pipeline invokes the same job to do a build, across a pool of build machines, so we can just use that build number to increment the version.  For example I have v1.2 being worked on by several branches, each having a CI, Nightly, and Release pipelines.  They all invoke the same build sub-job so you might have CI/BranchA run sub-job #503 on buildVM1 so will have version string 1.2.503, then Nightly/BranchB will run sub-job #504 on buildVM2 so will have version string 1.2.504.  This works great as long as I am invoking the same build sub-job.

The next step is to implement the builds as part of the Jenkinsfile pipeline, but then I lose my convenient build increment.  How can I define a shared build increment for this component across all branches defining the same major.minor version?

Timestamp is a bit unwieldy since the multiple branches/teams/build machines means I need to go to seconds.  Do I really need versions like 1.2.20180118165007?  There's got to be a better way.

How else can I manage this?